# system.io.streamwriter writeline

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

i am writing each line to a text file:

> Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
>
> ```
>         For Each x In tofile
>              objWriter.WriteLine(x)
>          Next
> ```
>
> objWriter.Close()

which works perfecly the only problem is is that when its finished it writes a blank line on the end of the text file which i dont want. is thair anyway of getting round this?

or if not remove the last line so long as its blank?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tofile))
```

This will have same effect as your current code just without having to mess around with the stream yourself.

Also possible:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, tofile)
```

Assuming `tofile` is plain array of strings.

If for some reason you do need to use the Stream directly, just don't use `WriteLine` in the last iteration:

```
For i=1 To tofile.Length
    x = tofile(i)
    If i<tofile.Length Then
        objWriter.WriteLine(x)
    Else  
        objWriter.Write(x)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

WriteLine appends the Environment.NewLine after each write.
So you are not really appending one more line to you output.
You could prove it trying to read back your file with StreamReader.Readline()

Answer (score 0):

The WriteLine method is basically the same as the Write method, but adds a new line character on the end of its parameter. This is causing the problem here because it will add a new line character to the end of the last line as well, even though there is nothing following it.

If `tofile` can be cast to an array, you could replace the `For Each` loop with

```
objWriter.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, tofile.toArray()))
```

after replacing `toArray` with the relevant cast, of course.

However, in my opinion at least, a text file format shouldn't be so sensitive as to get messed up by a blank line.

Comment: I don't believe the "\n" will work in VB.  Use Environment.NewLine instead.